# A combinatorial problem arising from an exercise on the weil conjectures

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to learn a little bit about the Weil conjectures and specifically i'm trying to do exercise 5.5 in appendix C of Hartshorne. I'll try to explain quickly the problem so you don't have to read it in the book  but I think that I have reduced the problem to a purely combinatorial question so if you don't know algebraic geometry you can skip this preliminary part and go directly to the combinatorial question below.

So let's $C$ be a curve of genus $g$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Define $N_r = \# C(\mathbb{F}_{q^r})$. The question in Hartshorne is

**Show that $N_1,...,N_g$ determines $N_r$ for all $r \in \mathbb N$ using the weil conjectures**

So let me explain what the Weil conjectures tell us (again you can skip this and go to the combinatorial formulation of the question at the end).
We define the zeta function of $C$ to be
$$
Z(C,t) = exp (\sum_{i=1}^\infty N_r\frac{t^r} r )
$$

The Weil conjectures in the case of curves then tells you that in fact there exists a polynomial $P$ of degree $2g$ such that 
$$
Z(C,t) = \frac{P(t)}{(1-t)(1-qt)}
$$
where $P(0)=1$. It also tells you that if you write $a_1,...,a_{2g}$ for the reciprocals of the roots of $P$ (i.e. $P(t) = \prod (1 - a_it)$) then then you can order them so that $a_i = q/a_{2g-i}$ for all $i$ in $1,...,g$ and $|a_i|=q^{1/2}$.

Now it is easy to see that this implies that for all $r \in \mathbb N$ we have

$$
\sum_{i=1}^g a_i^r + \left(\frac q {a_i}\right)^r = q^r +1 - N_r
$$

**So here is my combinatorial question :**
Suppose you are given $g$ complex numbers $a_1,...,a_g$ such that $|a_i| = q^{1/2}$ for $q$ the power of a prime number.. For all $r \in \mathbb N$, write 
$$C_r = \sum_{i=1}^g a_i^r + \left(\frac q {a_i}\right)^r.
$$
 Then is it true that knowing $C_1,...,C_g$ implies that you know all the $C_r$ and if so why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote, for both positive and negative $r$,
$$A_r = \sum_{i=1}^{2g} a_i^r.$$
You have shown
$$N_r = 1 - q^r - A_r = 1 - q^r - q^rA_{-r}$$
and so once we specify $N_1,\ldots,N_g$, we have $A_{-g},\ldots,A_g$. We can get any other $A_r$, though, by using the so-called Newton identities (see Barry H. Dayton's *[Theory of Equations](http://barryhdayton.space/theoryEquations/textpartX.pdf),* Thms. 4.6.1 and 4.7.2), which say that if we denote
$$P(t) = t^{2g} + p_1t^{2g-1} + p_2t^{2g-2} + \cdots + p_{2g-1}t + p_{2g},$$
and $p_k = 0$ for $k < 0$, $k > 2g$ then
\begin{align}
A_r + p_1A_{r-1} + p_2A_{r-2} + \cdots + p_{r-1}A_1 + p_rr = 0, &\quad \text{for}\ r > 0\\
(2g-r)p_r + p_{r+1}A_{-1} + p_{r+2}A_{-2} + \cdots + p_{2g}A_{r-2g} = 0, &\quad \text{for}\ r \le 2g
\end{align}
This means we can get any $N_r$ as well, since $A_{-g},\ldots,A_g$ tell us what $p_1,\ldots,p_{2g}$ would be, and then by recursively solving for higher $A_r$.